# RegisterHotKey without a modifier in c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

This piece of code registers 2 global hotkeys under Windows for SHIFT+F5 and SHIFT+F6 it works fine in all cases, including the case that a completely other application has the focus like for example a game.

```
enum{ KEY_F5 = 1, KEY_F6 = 2 };  
RegisterHotKey(0, KEY_F5, MOD_SHIFT, VK_F5);  
RegisterHotKey(0, KEY_F6, MOD_SHIFT, VK_F6);  
MSG msg;  
while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
{
    PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, 0);
    switch (msg.message){

    case WM_HOTKEY:
        if (msg.wParam == KEY_F5){
            // code
        }
        else if (msg.wParam == KEY_F6){
            // code
        }
    }
}
```

But if i replace

```
RegisterHotKey(0, KEY_F5, MOD_SHIFT, VK_F5);  
RegisterHotKey(0, KEY_F6, MOD_SHIFT, VK_F6);
```

by

```
RegisterHotKey(0, KEY_F5, 0, VK_F5);  
RegisterHotKey(0, KEY_F6, 0, VK_F6);
```

because my goal is it two have F5 and F6 as hotkeys without having to press SHIFT always, it only works if my program has the focus not if some other has. How can i achieve to have only F? as global hotkey like for example TS3 does. It must work even if the application doesn't have the focus.

Comment: Why does your code show you registering a hotkey as `KEY_F5` but checking for `ONE_KEYID` ?

Comment: You'll need to make sure your app's uninstaller works well. It will get a lot of use.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is `RegisterHotKey(NULL, KEY_F5, 0, VK_F5);`, just as you did. BUT. There is a problem. You should study API reference before you use it. From [`RegisterHotKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey):

> RegisterHotKey fails if the keystrokes specified for the hot key have already been registered by another hot key.

So, if another program had already registered bare `F5` and/or `F6` hotkeys, your `RegisterHotKey` function call will fail and return `FALSE`. You should have checked the return result and then used `GetLastError()`. You would get this message:

```
[E1409] Hot key is already registered.
```

Now, to get around this problem you can try to launch your program at startup as fast as you can, to hope to grab that hotkeys for yourself, and then keep your program up and running forever.

Another, more advanced and fail proof thing you can try is to set global keyboard hook. There is a ton of information on how to setup hooks. You can start here: [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa).

Answer (score -1):

Try use `MOD_NOREPEAT` instead of `MOD_SHIFT`. I also don't see any necessity of using "PeakMessage". Since you already call `GetMessage()`, PeakMessage is really redundant.